# Div under grid in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a layout that is a sidebar and a grid both wrapped in a flexbox. I'd like to put a div underneath the grid so it can have prev/next buttons, like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqM8a.png), but I can't figure out how to do that. The grid resizes itself with the window so the grid can take as many rows as necessary and then the div should go below that, and be as wide as the grid.

This is what I have, but the div is on the right of the grid:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Boardgame Database</title>
<style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    aside {
        background-color: red;
        flex: 1;
        min-width: 250px;
    }

    .grid-container {
        flex: 4;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    }

    .grid-item {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 24px;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #flex-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="flex-container">
    <aside class="sidebar">
    </aside>

    <section class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-item">1</div>
            <div class="grid-item">2</div>
            <div class="grid-item">3</div>
            <div class="grid-item">4</div>
            <div class="grid-item">5</div>
            <div class="grid-item">6</div>
            <div class="grid-item">7</div>
            <div class="grid-item">8</div>
            <div class="grid-item">9</div>
            <div class="grid-item">10</div>
            <div class="grid-item">11</div>
            <div class="grid-item">12</div>
            <div class="grid-item">13</div>
            <div class="grid-item">14</div>
            <div class="grid-item">15</div>
            <div class="grid-item">16</div>
            <div class="grid-item">17</div>
            <div class="grid-item">18</div>

    </section>

    <div id="page-buttons">
        <a href="test.html?page=1">prev</a>
        <a href="test.html?page=5">next</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use nested flex containers. Section and bottom div should be wrapped inside another flex container with flex direction to column.
So outer flex will make sidebar & inner flex container to be side by side.
Or just use a normal div container instead of flex.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following Code.

```css
#main{
display :flex;
}
#sidebar{
width:70px;
height: 300px;

border: solid black 1px;
}
#grid-area{
width:200px;
height: 300px;
border: solid black 1px;
display: block;
}
#grid{
width:200px;
height: 250px;
border: solid black 1px;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="grid-area">
<div id="grid"></div>
<div id="button">next / prev</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another example only with grid keeping the pre/next button at the bottom of the viewport:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(250px, 1fr) 4fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}

aside {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0.25em;
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-column: 1;
}

section,
#page-buttons {
  grid-column: 2;
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: 0.25em;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

#page-buttons {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: lightgray;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-container">
  <aside class="sidebar">
  </aside>

  <section class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">5</div>
    <div class="grid-item">6</div>
    <div class="grid-item">7</div>
    <div class="grid-item">8</div>
    <div class="grid-item">9</div>
    <div class="grid-item">10</div>
    <div class="grid-item">11</div>
    <div class="grid-item">12</div>
    <div class="grid-item">13</div>
    <div class="grid-item">14</div>
    <div class="grid-item">15</div>
    <div class="grid-item">16</div>
    <div class="grid-item">17</div>
    <div class="grid-item">18</div>
  </section>

  <div id="page-buttons">
    <a href="test.html?page=1">prev</a>
    <a href="test.html?page=5">next</a>
  </div>

</div>
```